# What am I doing wrong with XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to manipulate xsd schema as an xml document that should not be a problem, I believe. But facing troubles with XPath. Whatever XPath I try, it returns nothing. Tried it with or without namespaces but no success.
Please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

My xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.mydomain.com" xmlns="http://www.mydomain.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:complexType name="Label">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="Listener"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

and application code is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setValidating(false);
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
domFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
domFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

try {
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dDoc = builder.parse("C:/Temp/test.xsd");

    // This part works
    Node rootNode = dDoc.getElementsByTagName("xs:schema").item(0);
    System.out.println(rootNode.getNodeName());

    // This part doesn't work
    XPath xPath1 = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nList1 = (NodeList) xPath1.evaluate("//xs:schema", dDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);  
    System.out.println(nList1.item(0).getNodeName());

    // This part doesn't work
    XPath xPath2 = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nList2 = (NodeList) xPath2.evaluate("//xs:element", rootNode, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
    System.out.println(nList2.item(0).getNodeName());

}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a namespace context using XPath.setNamespaceContext(). This binds the `xs` prefix to the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace.

Comment: and then xPath1.evaluate("//schema",...) should do the trick?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: No. `//schema` means any `schema` element in the tree under no namespace. Should be `/xs:schema`

Answer (score 3):

Made changes to your code. It works:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XPathtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        domFactory.setValidating(false);
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        domFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        domFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dDoc = builder.parse("C:/Temp/test.xsd");

            // This part works
            Node rootNode = dDoc.getElementsByTagName("xs:schema").item(0);
            System.out.println(rootNode.getNodeName());

            // This part doesn't work
            XPath xPath1 = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            NamespaceContext nsContext = new NamespaceContext() {

                @Override
                public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                    return "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
                }

                @Override
                public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                    return "xs";
                }

                @Override
                public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                    Set s = new HashSet();
                    s.add("xs");
                    return s.iterator();
                }

            };

            xPath1.setNamespaceContext((NamespaceContext) nsContext);

            NodeList nList1 = (NodeList) xPath1.evaluate("//xs:schema", dDoc,
                    XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println(nList1.item(0).getNodeName());

            // This part doesn't work
            // XPath xPath2 = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            NodeList nList2 = (NodeList) xPath1.evaluate("//xs:element",
                    rootNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println(nList2.item(0).getNodeName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you haven't specified what `xs` means. An xml parser must know the namespace url, `xs` is just an identifier.

You can demonstrate this yourself by using the following code:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

SimpleNamespaceContext nsContext = new SimpleNamespaceContext();
nsContext.addNamespace("t", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
xPath.setNamespaceContext(nsContext);

xPath.evaluate("//t:schema", dDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

You can see that I now use the identifier `t` instead of `xs` but that doesn't matter as long as you use the same namespace url.

Comment: You should `import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.SimpleNamespaceContext` first or something similar, because the JDK doesn't contain an implementation of `javax.xml.namespace.Namespace`.